# My view change when i change my local english to arabic how can i stop this?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, desktop-application, flutter-web

My view change when change my language english to arabic how can i prevent this.

```
   EasyLocalization(
    supportedLocales: [
      Locale('en', 'US'),
      Locale('ar', 'SA'),
      Locale('en', 'GB'),
    ],
    path: 'assets/lang',
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your own `builder` for `MaterialApp` to force LTR directionality.

```
MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: child!,
    );
  },
)
```